# Issue with my code

Tags: java, constructor

I'm having a problem with my code. I know that it has to do something with a Count constructor and its parameters. However, I can't wrap my mind around it.

What parameters should I add to the Count constructor to make the code work?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CH9Assignment
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        count();
        //Create Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in) ;
        System.out.println ("Enter a sentence:");
        String s1 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("Enter 1 to count characters, 2 to count words");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        if (x == 1)
            System.out.println ("There are " + s1.length() + "characters");
    }


    public static int count(String word) 
    {
        if (word == null || word.isEmpty()) 
        { 
            return 0; 
        } 
        int wordCount = 0; 
        boolean isWord = false; 
        int endOfLine = word.length() - 1; 
        char[] characters = word.toCharArray(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) 
        { 
            if (Character.isLetter(characters[i]) && i != endOfLine) 
            { 
                isWord = true; 
            } 
            else if (!Character.isLetter(characters[i]) && isWord) 
            { 
                wordCount++; isWord = false;
            } 
            else if (Character.isLetter(characters[i]) && i == endOfLine) 
            { 
                wordCount++; 
            }

            if (x == 2)
                System.out.println ("There are " + wordCount + "words"); 

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: count is not a constructor

Answer (score 1):

You only have one method called count, it requires a String parameter, yet you try to call it without parameters.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CH9Assignment
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
      //  count(); --> DELETE THIS CALL, you don't have such a method
    //Create Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in) ;
    System.out.println ("Enter a sentence:");
    String s1 = input.nextLine();
    int result = count(s1); // ADD THIS LINE
    System.out.println ("Enter 1 to count characters, 2 to count words");
    int x = input.nextInt();
    if (x == 1)
        System.out.println ("There are " + s1.length() + "characters");
}

// Your count method

}
```

This will solve the compilation issues. You should be able to work out the logical issues.

Comment: I see it now, thanks a lot. I'm having another issue with my variable x at line 46. I get an error that variable x cannot be found.                                                     

                       
                
            if (x == 2)
            System.out.println ("There are " + wordCount + "words"); 
                
                }

Comment: That is a problem of scope. you are declaring a local variable in your main method, the count method doesn't know it exists, let alone what value is assigned to it

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `count` method with something as a parameter. So just call it with `s1` as parameter inside the if block. Your `count` method also seems too big and blown up. So I changed it, to just split the string by a simple regex. Try the following snippet:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    //Create Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in) ;
    System.out.println ("Enter a sentence:");
    String s1 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("Enter 1 to count characters, 2 to count words");
    int x = input.nextInt();
    switch(x){
        case 1;
            System.out.println ("There are " + s1.length() + " characters");
            return;
        case 2:
            System.out.println ("There are " + count(s1) + " words");
            return;
    }
}

public static int count(String word){
    if(word == null || word.isEmpty()){
        return 0;
    }
    return word.split("(\\s|\\S)+").length;
}
```